# Is there a Japanese word for the game "horseshoes?"

Tags: translation, nuances, idioms

I'm guessing this will come across as two questions, but their interrelation is important...

Is there a specific word for the game where you toss a horseshoe at a peg (in English just called horseshoes)?

Obviously a literal translation would be 蹄鉄｛ていてつ}, but would a native speaker understand it in context of the game, i.e. 蹄鉄を遊ぶ or 蹄鉄やろう, or in an even more complex context such as "'close enough' only counts in horseshoes," even if they weren't directly aware of the English idiom, such as:

```
いい線とは蹄鉄と州榴弾しか関係ない。
```

("Close enough only matters with horseshoes and hand grenades")

Or perhaps:

```
「ほとんど」とは蹄鉄と手榴弾しか関係ない。
```

("'Almost' only matters with horseshoes and hand grenades")

Note that I'm not looking for a similar idiom in Japanese, I'm looking for a direct translation of the English, even if it sounds awkward, so long as the listener knows about the game horseshoes and that being close but missing still counts.

**EDIT:**

Based on the answers given so far, I've come up with the following dialog for two characters in a story and would like to know if it makes sense:

```
 「あのつちぐもにほとんど食われそうだったのにあんたいい機嫌だよね、カレン。」

 「アメリカではとあることわざがある。ほとんどって言葉はホースシューズと手榴弾の場合でしか関係ない。
　まぁ、翻訳で少し何かがなくしたかもね。。。」とカレンは頑張って訳試して見た。

 「骨子ぐらい分かったわよ。つまり、いくら惜しくても外れは外れ
   当たらなければ何にもならないってことか？」とのぞみは答えた。

 「そう、そう！何が起こったことでもあろうと、あの化け物に食われなかったら問題なし！」
```

Comment: We don't have horseshoes or the derived expression here in Britain.

Comment: Even so, I'd imagine in Britain that they'd understand "Close enough only counts in hand grenades."

Comment: Okay, (1) ホースシューズ doesn't ring a bell for me but it may be okay because it appears as a passage that doesn't making sense in the dialog; (2) you can't use the word ほとんど in that context; (3) "missing" is fortunate for you in that situation, but my answer was on the basis that "missing" is unfortunate, so the great part of my answer is actually invalid...

Comment: What would be a better word than ほとんど in that context? 危うく perhaps?

Comment: @stix I said it wrong. ほとんど in the second line can't be associated with that in the first line, because what translates your "almost" in the Japanese is not ほとんど but ほとんど……そう (which is not a single word). Anyway, 当たる is also pointless in this context, so perhaps you can open a new question about translation of this idiom if you seek it.

Answer (score 4):

Horseshoes hadn't be used until Meiji in Japan, naturally no specific word for the horseshoe-tossing game. You can just literally say 蹄鉄投げ. FYI in the video game Rimworld, an item [*horseshoes pin*](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Horseshoes_pin) is translated [輪投げのピン](https://wikiwiki.jp/rimworld/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%A1%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC#dcc731c4) "hoop toss pin" which sounds way more familiar than the horseshoes, though the description and the graphic clearly tell that it's actually horseshoes that are thrown.

[image]
[image]

Note that traditional 輪投げ usually requires hoops to be thrown exactly over the pin, so... close doesn't count.

For that reason or not, there's no idiom like "Close enough only matters with horseshoes and hand grenades" if I'm correct that this literal situation is the moral of the phrase. You have to explain, and what is worse, English "close" and "almost" in this sense is fairly ambiguous in Japanese, so you aren't likely to get the sole versatile translation. In the first place it divides into whether "missing" is undesired:

> 惜しいが通用するのは蹄鉄投げと手榴弾だけ
>   （蹄鉄投げの）蹄鉄と手榴弾以外は当たらないと話にならない

or desired:

> （蹄鉄投げの）蹄鉄と手榴弾以外は当たらなければどうということはない
>   （蹄鉄投げの）蹄鉄と手榴弾以外はかすらなければ全部同じ

(**Edit**: Though those sentences let listeners infer that horseshoes is something "counts even if missing", the fact is not known a priori to the average Japanese. Darts and curling might be better examples of such games for the purpose of explanation to Japanese.)

**Edit 2**:

Translation in context is nothing like the sum of that of individual words. I provide a natural version of your sample dialog, please see how the explanation above is inapplicable without context:

> 「カレン、あんたあのつちぐもにあと一歩で食われるところだったのに上機嫌ね」
>
> 「アメリカにはこんなことわざがあってね。『蹄鉄投げと手榴弾でなければ、あと一歩かどうかは関係ない』
>   まぁ、翻訳じゃ伝わらないかもしれないけど」
>   カレンは頑張って訳をひねり出して言った。
>
> 「雰囲気ぐらいは分かったわよ。つまりいくらギリギリでも、そうならなかったら全部同じってことでしょ？」とのぞみは答えた。
>
> 「そう、そう！途中何があろうと、あの化け物に食われなかったんだから問題なし！」

Comment: The term 馬【ば】蹄【てい】 is cited [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%AC%E8%B9%84-603106#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) in a text from 814, over a thousand years before the Meiji Period. Do you mean that _metal_ horseshoes only appear from the Meiji Period?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 馬蹄 means horse hooves...

Comment: Derp!  Yes, you're correct.  Brain fart on my part, got my wires crossed.  However, there were still pre-Meiji 馬【うま】沓【ぐつ】, as 草鞋【わらじ】 instead of 鉄【てつ】.  There may have also been 蹄【てい】鉄【てつ】 during the 戦【せん】国【ごく】時【じ】代【だい】.  C.f. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/蹄鉄#日本における蹄鉄.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Hmm... interesting. If that's correct they had _horsesandals_ instead of _horseshoes_ ;D should I add that they didn't have a hole in the center?

Comment: Hah! I love it. Googling for "horsesandal" led me to [this article about _hipposandals_](http://www.mashpedia.net/Hipposandal), apparently used in ancient Rome, which look very like the horse 草鞋【わらじ】, only made of leather. 勉強になりました！

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi (ﾟДﾟ;） many a true word is spoken in jest...

Comment: Does ギリギリ work in this context? I was under the impression ギリギリ was more related to time than distance. 

As far as missing being desired or not, in the context of the English idiom they're somewhat the same. "Being close" is good enough (or bad enough) only if it's a grenade. If you're the one throwing the grenade, you're happy with "close enough" if you're the one being thrown at, you certainly aren't, but if it isn't a grenade (i.e. something that has to hit), you're fine with being missed by a very close margin, but if you're the one throwing, being close isn't good enough.

Comment: Additionally, I really like the 「。。。そうならなかったら全部同じってこと。。。」 part as it very well captures the essence of the English: No matter how close it is, if it doesn't connect it's the same as not happening at all.

Comment: @stix ぎりぎり→ https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58228/meaning/m0u/ And yes, I know there is no good or bad meaning of "close" in English, but this is a lexical lacuna that can't be helped. "Brother" just has one meaning in English, but you know...

Comment: @stix I'm glad you like it, but be reminded that it's not the "definitive" translation either (at least not when the previous event can't be described using なる). Moreover, if you don't need to use a value-neutral word, doing so is always more fitting.

Comment: Another question (though perhaps I'm asking too many in comments that could be their own questions):

Why the use of 雰囲気 over 骨子? I definitely can see how 雰囲気 fits, but the original English here is "gist," as in the basic or fundamental understanding of an idea. Why doesn't 骨子 work in such a case?

Comment: @stix Then you can use 趣旨, or say 言いたいことは分かる. 雰囲気 more like that you have a "rough sketch". And 骨子 is a bookish word that literally means "skeleton; outline; summary (of a plan)". Sometimes it's the same as "gist", sometimes not.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the initial non-idiomatic question,

> Is there a Japanese word for the game “horseshoes?”

Yes.

- [Per Eijirō](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=horseshoe), 蹄【てい】鉄【てつ】投【な】げ遊【あそ】び is one option.
- [Per the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B9%84%E9%89%84#%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B3%E9%81%93%E5%85%B7%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%B9%84%E9%89%84), just katakana-ize it to ホースシューズ.